# NDB fetch model instance from Key using projection?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a relatively large model class that I can access by key id, e.g.:

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    propA = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    probB = ndb.StringProperty()
    probC = ndb.JsonProperty()

key = ndb.Key('Foo', 1234)
model = key.get()
```

If I only need 'propA' from this model at this time, is there a way to create a projection=[Foo.propA] type request without creating an unnecessary query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries are not necessarily more expensive than direct reads.  How about:

```
model = Foo.Query('__key__'=key).fetch(1, projection=[Foo.propA])
```